# How to traslate a whole html page with ngx translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

My privacy policy is embedded as full html. I would like to translate it with ngx-translate but it would be much to time expensive and completely unstructured if I would translate it per html tag as ngx-translate suggests it. 
This is what the policy is designed like:

```
<h1>Datenschutzerklärung</h1>
    <p>Verantwortlicher im Sinne der Datenschutzgesetze, insbesondere der EU-Datenschutzgrundverordnung (DSGVO), ist:
    </p>
    <p>Chinaedu Pascal Onwukwe</p>
    <h2 id="betroffenenrechte">Ihre Betroffenenrechte</h2>
    <p>Unter den angegebenen Kontaktdaten unseres Datenschutzbeauftragten können Sie jederzeit folgende Rechte ausüben:
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>Auskunft über Ihre bei uns gespeicherten Daten und deren Verarbeitung (Art. 15 DSGVO),</li>
      <li>Berichtigung unrichtiger personenbezogener Daten (Art. 16 DSGVO),</li>
      <li>Löschung Ihrer bei uns gespeicherten Daten (Art. 17 DSGVO),</li>
      <li>Einschränkung der Datenverarbeitung, sofern wir Ihre Daten aufgrund gesetzlicher Pflichten noch nicht löschen
        dürfen (Art. 18 DSGVO),</li>
      <li>Widerspruch gegen die Verarbeitung Ihrer Daten bei uns (Art. 21 DSGVO) und</li>
      <li>Datenübertragbarkeit, sofern Sie in die Datenverarbeitung eingewilligt haben oder einen Vertrag mit uns
        abgeschlossen haben (Art. 20 DSGVO).</li>
    </ul> ...
```

I would like to find a way on how to translate this without translating each single html tag but more like replacing an html file. Does anybody know how I would do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add html into the translation file and then just inject that. You might wanna bypass the dom sanitizer for this purpose. Otherwise cou can create some custom logic that switches over the current language and loads a static asset into the dom.

Comment: is ngx-translate maybe the wrong way? complete html files should serve static in assets in different versions like
de.html
en.html
es.html
and load by service

Comment: Could you please give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can translate an HTML template using the `instant` method of `TranslateService` with `DomSanitizer` service. Something like this:

component.ts

```
constructor(
  public translate: TranslateService,
  public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
) {}

getTranslatedHtmlSnippet(s: string): SafeHtml {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.translate.instant('HOME.TEXT'));
}
```

and you can inject with `innerHtml` the translated HTML.

template.html

```
<div [innerHtml]="getTranslatedHtmlSnippet()"></div>
```

In order to work, you must provide a different template in the translation file.

i18n.json

```
{
  "HOME": {
    "TEXT": "<div style='color: red;'> eng <div>"
  }
}
```

I leave you  a link to stackbliz to see a running example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translation-service-cpupat

However, I suggest you NOT use this kind of approach and always translate only string/content, not structure.
If you really need this kind of translation and is not restricted to a single component is better to create a pipe.